# Apache Wink, GET and JSON consumer, how?

Tags: json, curl

how do I send a valid request via CURL for this Apache Wink handler?

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject find(JSONObject request) {
// ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I realize this is an old thread but I wanted to answer it in case someone stumbles over the question as I have*

Try:

```
@GET
@Path ( "{json}" )
@Produces  (MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
public JSONObject find(@PathParam("json") JSONObject json)
{
    ...
}
```